# How can I identify the clicked widget?

Tags: android, widget

I created three widgets on my home screen and I want to change each one's view separately. So when I do click on widget , it always detect that I click the last created widget (See below the displayed Toast in `onReceive` method). How can I detect click from different widgets separately and identify the active widget  ?

Here is my code :

```
public class SimpleWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

    private final String TAG="SimpleWidgetTAG" ;
    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        final int count = appWidgetIds.length;

        Log.i(TAG,"  onUpdate ") ;

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            int widgetId = appWidgetIds[i];
            String number = String.format("Item %d =  %03d ", i,(new Random().nextInt(900) + 100));

            RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                    R.layout.simple_widget);
            remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.textView, number);

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, SimpleWidgetProvider.class);
            intent.setAction(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE);

            intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, widgetId);

            intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, appWidgetIds);

            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
                    0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.actionButton, pendingIntent);
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetId, remoteViews);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        super.onReceive(context, intent);
        int widgetID = intent.getIntExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, -1);

        if(intent.getAction().equals(AppWidgetManager.ACTION_APPWIDGET_UPDATE)) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Updated " + widgetID, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        Log.i(TAG,"  onReceive "+intent+"  , \n widgetId = "+widgetID) ;

    }

}
```